# Eclipse(STS)/Maven integration issues

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am working on a fairly big project that uses maven for dependency management. As part of this we are using Maven profiles to build and replace certain properties files that differ between test/dev/production environments.

To perform a build I would execute a Maven:build using the correct profile and mavens reactor would then build the projects in the correct order and store the jars in the .m2 folder, eg the domain jar first, then the service jar (with the domain jar included in its jar as a dependency) etc. This leads to a war file eventually with all the correct libs required by the war to run.

When eclipse performs its default build that it performs everytime you save a file the jars are not built with any profile, just a regular build.

When I then push the final war file to the server and it is exploded when the server starts up (started and deployed through eclipse) I get in the lib folder all the jars that maven had packaged into the war file but also all the jars that eclipse had built.

eg

```
lib/
    domain.jar (built by eclipse)
    domain.SNAPSHOT.1.0.jar (built by maven)
    etc
```

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? This has the end consequence of there being two of every property file and only the order in which they are loaded determines which is used. A real hassle as different properties are used in different environments.

Comment: Have you imported the project in Eclipse as Maven Project ? does the Build on command line work ok ? You are using "mvn install" instead of first "mvn clean package"...

Comment: Do you have the finalName property defined in multiple places in your POM(s)?

Comment: My full Maven Build Goal is: clean install -PprofileTest. Checking the times on the jar files inside the exploded war on the Tomcat the modified date states that the domain.jar was built at say 10.00 and the domain.SNAPSHOT.1.0.jar was built at 10.06 (where my full build and deploy took i would estimate 6 minutes). This isn't a maven issue as much as it is eclipse trying to resolve the dependencies and pushing its own version of the jars to the server, I think.

Comment: You should specify which version of m2e you are using since the old and new versions behave very, very differently.

Comment: I'm using SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) which comes with the m2e plugin preinstalled. I have tried to update it but it seems so interwoven that the original m2e it comes with can't be extricated. It seems to be version 0.12.1.20110112-1712.

Comment: m2e migrated to the Eclipse foundation and is now on version 1.x.y, and has come a long way.  I would try backing up your eclipse instance and try uninstalling the old one and installing the new one.  I'm not sure about the old one, but in the new one you can set profiles.  Let me know if this works so I can put it up as an answer.

Comment: yeah, problem is that the new version of eclipse and m2e forces an update to the maven projects, which conflicts with the rest of the team and our hudson server. thanks anyway, going to go with the hacky solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a slightly hacky solution to this problem.

In the web projects properties -> Deployment Assembly I modified the path for the offending jar files eg `domain.jar` from

`WEB-INF/lib/domain.jar`

to

`WEB-INF/autogen/domain.jar`

This leads to the eclipse generated jar files (with the wrong properties files) to be deployed to a folder that won't be loaded when tomcat starts. Not a perfect solution but it allows all the nice things of eclipse auto-building like code completion and error messages in the web project if the interface of the domain changes etc while also providing the correct profile when deployed.

Leaving this here for anyone else in this situation.

Comment: From what I've seen, this is a fairly common solution when m2e doesn't cooperate.

Comment: Removing the accept on this answer. Even this hasn't completely solved the issue. The problem is that every time maven refreshes the dependencies it will change the files back to WEB_INF/lib/domain.jar.

Also after a refresh (regularly required to force eclipse to recognise that a maven build has completed) it will cause build path issues as all files referencing that jar will be unable to use it. 

I'm thinking I might write a few lines into the tomcat startup.bat script to delete the files before tomcat startup.

Comment: Try going in the other direction - change the directory maven puts the files into, and then make sure that directory maps back into the proper war directory.